# Get internet working on newly installed ubuntu

Tags: internet, vpn, tls

I live in kashmir valley where we were under communication blackout since Aug 5. The govt has recently restored phone networks and access to 301 whitelisted websites like travel, education, and other govt sites and that too only 2G network. I am using tls tunnel on my smartphone to access the forbidden internet since most vpns are not working due to being blocked. I was wondering if i could get internet working on my ubuntu. It is a minimal install and all ubuntu servers are blocked so not even "apt update" working.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility I can think of is V2Ray.

There is a list of the 301 whitelisted websites on the Internet. Github is listed among them. Therefore you should be able to reach https://github.com/v2ray/v2ray-core/releases and download the V2Ray client for Ubuntu. I believe `v2ray-linux-64.zip` is the download you need for the client. I do not know if it will work without access to `apt update`.

For the server, you will need access to a VPS outside Kashmir, or to a friend who can set the VPS up for you. You would need to disguise the VPS as one of the 301 whitelisted web servers. Configuring the server is a little bit complicated, and you would need to follow a tutorial if you have never done it before.

Once you have configured the server, you can configure the client with matching details.

Comment: Thanks for advice but if i disguised a vps as a whitelisted web server, I am looking at a long time behind bars. We are under extreme scrunity and doing such a thing is risky since some rebels also do it. But still thank you very much. Can't i make the outgoing traffic look like it is going to whitelisted web when i am browsing askubuntu.

Comment: I do not know any way to do that.